# mysql select .. where .. in -> optimizing

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I have a table with a number of columns and ~15K rows. Most important among these are three we'll call 'a', 'b' and 'c'. I have an index on these columns in that order (a, b, c).

When I do a 'desc select * from <table> where a = <some value> or a = <some other value>' Im told that it grabs the value with 2 rows. This is expected.

When I do a 'desc select * from <table> where a in <some list of values>' Im told that it isn't using the index at all.

Why not? Is there some way to create an index such that 'where <column> in <list of values>' is indexed?

Comment: `where field in ('a','b','c')` is no different than `if (field='a') or (field='b') or (field='c')`. However, sometimes mysql will decide it's simply easier to do a full table scan, even if an index could be used.

Comment: Since it would have to search the index several times and 15k rows aren't that many it probably estimates that a table scan is faster.  if (field='a') or (field='b') or (field='c') will probably also skip the index. Try to insert the values in your IN()-clause into a temp table and use a join instead.

Comment: Yep. I redid it as a join and its much happier now. ty.

Comment: did you do  show index from <table>?