# Searching a text for predefined words

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, data-mining

Hi I have a database table that looks like this

```
word_id int(10)
word varchar(30)
```

And I have a text, I wanna see which one of the words in this text are defined in that table, what's the most elegant way of doing this?

Currently I query the database for all the words, then using PHP I search for each word in the whole text, so it takes a long time for PHP to download all the words from database, and then it checks each and everyone of them against my text.

Comment: Have you considered splitting the text into words and searching the DB for each word (reverse your current approach)? It would be much more efficient.

Comment: What about using an existing search engine? There are several open source options. You could modify the code to query your database.

Comment: Whatever you do, beware of the clbuttic problem. (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to extract the words in the text and put them in a SELECT query like this:

```
$words = array_unique(get_words_in_text(...));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word IN (".implode(", ", $words)).")";
```

Might be that your SQL engine optimizes this statement. In any case, the database connection is utilized less than it is in your current approach.

You can also try to **temporarily create a separate word table** and add all words in the text to that table. Then you can perform a `JOIN` with the main word table. If both tables are indexed properly, this *might* be quite fast.

**EDIT:** This question/answer suggests that creating a temporary table is indeed faster (see comments): [mysql select .. where .. in -> optimizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353974/mysql-select-where-in-optimizing). However, it certainly depends on the concrete database you're using, the size of your word table, the size of the texts and the configuration of your index(es). Thus, I recommend evaluating both approaches for your specific scenario. Please report your results. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

```
// get words in file into array
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$file_words = explode(" ", $file);

// remove duplicate words, count elements in array after de-duplication
$file_words = array_unique($file_words);
$file_count = count($file_words);

// create empty array in which to store hits
$words_with_definition = array();

// check to see if each word exists in database
for ($i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++)
{
    // intentionally leaving out db connection, this is just a concept
    // word should be at least three characters, change as needed
    if (strlen($file_words[$i]) >= 3)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT word FROM your_table WHERE word='".$file_words[$i]."'";

        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        {
            // this is a hit, add it to $words_with_definition
            array_push($words_with_definition, $file_words[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever is in the $words_with_definition array will be the words that hit off the database.